# Simulating touch event from QT Application

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a QT Application which receives `X&Y coordinates` and I need to simulate touch events (touch or long touch) using these coordinates.

I read in QT Reference documentation that `QTouchEventSequence` class can be used to simulate touch events. I am pretty new to QT and I have no idea how can I use it in an application. Could anybody help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to use QtTest module. It has a good [tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtestlib-tutorial.html).

For quick start here are a quick example for QTouchEventSequence:

```
// file test.cc
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtTest>


// This widget will receive touch events
class MyWidget: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyWidget(QWidget* parent = NULL)
      : QWidget(parent)
    {
        // With out this flag widget shouldn't receive any TouchEvent.
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
    }

protected:
    bool event(QEvent* e)
    {
        switch(e->type())
        {
            case QEvent::TouchBegin:
            case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
            case QEvent::TouchEnd:
                emit newTouchEvent(); // We will catch this in our test
                return true;
            default:
                return QWidget::event(e);
        }
    }

signals:
    void newTouchEvent();
};


// Here out test
class TouchTest: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private slots:
    void simpleTest();
};

void TouchTest::simpleTest()
{
    MyWidget widget;
    widget.show();
    QSignalSpy spy(&widget, SIGNAL(newTouchEvent()));

    // Simulate touch event
    QTest::touchEvent(&widget).press(0, QPoint(10, 10));

    QCOMPARE(spy.count(), 1);  // Did we called our signal. Yes. Cool!
}

QTEST_MAIN(TouchTest)
#include "test.moc"
```

You sould run moc, qmake and make to run it:

```
qmake -project "CONFIG += qtestlib"
qmake
moc test.cc > test.moc
make
./test
```

Comment: Thanks graphite. I could test it in tablet and it worked :). One more query i have. This touch event will occur on the widget. Is there anyway to make the touch event on the screen without specifying a particular widget. In my application I need to simulate the touch event without using a particular widget. Is it possible?

Comment: It looks you can't do it with Qt. And it will be system dependent. For Xorg on Linux you can have a look at [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) and make something similar in your program.

Comment: Ok. Is there any other way to give touch inputs to Windows?